# Woocommerce Get the order_id from one of the item_id?

Tags: woocommerce, edit, orders, items

I try to get the related order (the order id) from one of the line items id.

One case for example:
When editing an order, and deleting a line item (done by Ajax) the Woocommerce only provide the hook `"woocommerce_before_delete_order_item"` and passes `$item_id` only. (The woo function performs sql and not WP enviroment). I need the "belonging" order id to make some action!

My solution so far, is to loop through all orders and compare the Items ID, and break and return order ID when the match occurs.

This is way to slow, or "bulky clumsy", when keeping 10000 orders and more alive in the current shop.

**This does NOT work:**

> `wp_get_post_parent_id ( $item_id )`

But Im hoping there is a similar call, or do I need to make a DB `SQL` search? Any answer involving `mySQL`, please make it "copy and paste ready". Im great at PHP but dont handle or never write my own SQL.

Thanks for any help! Below is my solution so far:

```
$order_id = my_wc_get_order_from_item_id($item_id);

function my_wc_get_order_from_item_id($id) {

    $orders = get_posts('post_type=shop_order&numberposts=-1&post_status=publish');
    foreach($orders as $obj) {
        $order = new WC_Order($obj->ID);
        if ( count( $order->get_items('line_item') ) > 0 ) { 
            foreach($order->get_items('line_item') as $item_id => $item ) {
                if($item_id == $id) $return_value = $obj->ID;
                if(isset($return_value)) break;
            }
        }
        unset($order);
        if(isset($return_value)) break;
    }

    if(isset($return_value)) return $return_value;
        else return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach didn't work because order items are not posts in the `wp_posts` table, so they can't have a `post_parent`.

However, all is not lost and this was easier than I expected considering that my SQL isn't that strong. Looking at the `woocommerce_order_item` table in the database you can see that `order_id` and `order_item_id` are both there: [image: woocommerce_order_item table]

so I borrowed a little SQL statement from WooCommerce and modified it to find the `order_id` given a particular `order_item_id` row. Let me know how that works.

```
function so_38286531_get_order_item_order_id( $item_id ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $order_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT order_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items
         WHERE order_item_id = %d",
        $item_id
    ) );

    return $order_id;
}
```

Comment: Excellent: https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#1239

Comment: Thanks! What's the link to? The line number points to `'line_tax'` which doesn't seem related to this question/answer.

Comment: Apparently they have a problem with line numbers on WC API DOCS. Because if you look to my URL is pointing line 1239, but it shows line 1277… Line 1239 is very similar to your code and is related to get_items() function

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. The line numbers don't match at all, but you're right `get_items()` is the reverse of what the OP described.

Comment: @helgatheviking Tested provided solution and it seems to work well.

Comment: @JonasLundman if it works, would you please accept this answer?

Comment: Why is it so hard? Just use the built-in woocommerce function `wc_get_order_id_by_order_item_id($item_get_id)` to get order ID and that's it

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in woocommerce function `wc_get_order_id_by_order_item_id($item_get_id)` to get order ID

```
// define the woocommerce_before_delete_order_item callback 
 function my_func_before_delete_order_item( $item_get_id ) { 
    
     $order_id = wc_get_order_id_by_order_item_id($item_get_id);

     // do what you need...
}; 
         
 // add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_delete_order_item', 'my_func_before_delete_order_item', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: That is a handy function! but it was added in [Jan 2017](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/commit/a1446c959186691609ca2cdf901c15693b9299d5) so was not available in 2016 when this question was posted. Going forward, that's definitely the easier approach.